# Rakuten ecservice API - Get orders

Tags: ruby

Is there a way I can import orders from a Rakuten Ecommerce?

I'm looking for some API documentation but I haven't found in Ruby or other language

Comment: Did you take a look at this? https://github.com/shoprev/rakuten-api

Comment: Yes, but I want to know if a can get `orders` from a rakuten ecommerce. In this, I cannot get orders

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, API docs do exist but in order to use the APIs to grab orders you'll need to be registered with them (Rakuten) as all API requests need to accompanied by an authorisation token.

For the UK, send an email to support@rakuten.co.uk and ask for the API doc which covers: Orders, Operation, Products and Inventory APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for a place to post the results of a BUNCH of trail and error. This work for the **JAPANESE** "楽天 WEB SERVER" API (specifically using the "RakutenPayOrderAPI") (information can be found here for owners of a Rakuten shop https://webservice.rms.rakuten.co.jp/merchant-portal/view?contents=/ja/common/1-1_service_index/rakutenpayorderapi/getorder )

I found this CURL script (which they provided) to work but had the hardest time getting it to work in my company's Rails app.

for YOUR_AUTH_HERE you need to take serviceSecret:licenseKey as a string and convert it to Base64 and then make sure that there are no trailing == signs from conversion. Then, as I did, put that in an ENV file.

```
curl -X POST   https://apikuten.co.jp/es/2.0/order/searchOrder/   -H 'Authorization: ESA YOUR_AUTH_HERE'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'   -d '{
"dateType" : 4,
"startDatetime" : "2019-03-29T00:00:00+0900",
"endDatetime" : "2019-03-30T00:00:00+0900",
"PaginationRequestModel" :
{
    "requestRecordsAmount" : 30,
    "requestPage" : 1,
    "SortModelList" : [
        {
            "sortColumn" : 1,
            "sortDirection" : 1
        }
    ]
}
}'
```

Like I said, after much trail and error here is what I came up with in rails using HTTParty:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

authorization = 'ESA ' + ENV['RAKUTEN_API']

get_orders_list = HTTParty.post("https://api.rms.rakuten.co.jp/es/2.0/order/searchOrder/",
    :headers => { "Authorization" => authorization,
        "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
    :body => { 
        "dateType" => 4, 
        "startDatetime" => "2019-03-31T00:00:00+0900",
        "endDatetime" => "2019-03-31T23:59:59+0900",
        "PaginationRequestModel" => {
            "requestRecordsAmount" => 1000,
            "requestPage" => 1,
            "SortModelList" => [{
                "sortColumn" => 1,
                "sortDirection" => 1 }]
    }}.to_json)
pp get_orders_list
```

You can then use the resulting response order numbers to request specific order data in up to a 100 orders at a time. Here's an example of how to continue the code to get that information as well:

```
if get_orders_list['orderNumberList'].length > 100
    orders_list_by_100 = get_orders_list['orderNumberList'].each_slice(100).to_a
    order_details = Array.new
    messages = Array.new
    orders_list_by_100.each do |sub_list|
        get_order_details = HTTParty.post("https://api.rms.rakuten.co.jp/es/2.0/order/getOrder/",
            :headers => { "Authorization" => authorization,
                "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
            :body => {"orderNumberList" => sub_list}.to_json)
        order_details << get_order_details["OrderModelList"]
        messages << get_order_details["MessageModelList"]
    end
else
    get_order_details = HTTParty.post("https://api.rms.rakuten.co.jp/es/2.0/order/getOrder/",
        :headers => { "Authorization" => authorization,
            "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
        :body => {"orderNumberList" => get_orders_list['orderNumberList']}.to_json)
    order_details = get_order_details["OrderModelList"]
    messages = get_order_details["MessageModelList"]
end
```

Hope this helps someone out there. If I had more time I'd learn how to make a gem and make this more accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone still is searching Rakuten api docs for orders: here is the [link](http://webservice.rakuten.de/documentation/method/get_orders) on api docs (DE) and token can be generated in Rakuten account (without contacting Rakuten support).